# Vertically center search box before and after inserting another elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(function() {

  $('.forminput input[type="text"]').on('input propertychange', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var visible = Boolean($this.val());
    $this.siblings('.glyphicon').toggleClass('hidden', !visible);
  }).trigger('propertychange'); //nema potrebe za njim

  $('.glyphicon').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val('')
      .trigger('propertychange').focus();
    $('.results').empty();
  });

  $('.forminput').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var typed = $('.nice').val();
    $.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?', {
      action: 'query',
      srsearch: typed,
      format: 'json',
      list: 'search'
    }, function(data) {
      $('.results').empty();
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data.query.search, function(index, item) {
        $('.results').append("<a class='append' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + "<div class='appendsearch'><h1>" + item.title + "</h1><p>" + item.snippet + "</p></div></a>")
      })
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(9, 43, 64);
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
  height: 90vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.glyphicon {
  color: #B2DFDB;
}

.textbox {
  text-align: center;
}

.randomArticle {
  color: #B2DFDB;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.randomArticle:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.randomArticle:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #B2DFDB;
}

form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form .nice {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

form .nice:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #B2DFDB;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #00897B;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.append {
  color: black;
}

.append:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.appendsearch {
  background: rgb(230, 230, 231);
  margin: 20px 70px 20px 70px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: black;
  border-left: 4px solid rgb(9, 43, 64);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.appendsearch h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.appendsearch p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.appendsearch:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='textbox'>
      <a class='randomArticle' href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random' target='_blank'>Click here for a random article</a>
      <form class='forminput'>
        <input class='nice' type='text'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove hidden'></span>
        <input class='button' type='submit' value='Search'>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class='results'></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body
```

I cant get elements to be vertically centered before and after search **results** are inserted. I tried a lot of options but all I get is situation where search box is inserted on the left side of search result. 
Here is the sample > http://codepen.io/Todorovic/pen/PGrqOp

Comment: Since the first thing that happens when running your code sample is `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` so you might want to fix that first

Comment: How should it look like? Where should the search box be aufter search results are inserted?

Comment: https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/wGqEga/
this is what I want to achive. its not the case in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to make this work, is to add some line of code with jQuery.
To to center div horizontally and vertically change css:

```
 $('.textbox').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : function() {return -$(this).outerWidth()/2},
        'margin-top' : function() {return -$(this).outerHeight()/2}
    });
```

For working with dimensions if you are not familiar check:

http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

And down in your code after submit form change again css of div to put it on top of page:

```
 $('.textbox').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'left' : '50%',
    'top':'0%',
    'margin-top' : '30px',
    'margin-left' : function() {return -$(this).outerWidth()/2},
});
```

After append results add margin-top for div:

```
  $('.results').css({       
          'margin-top': $('.textbox').height()
      })     
  })
```

Here is CodePen example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRZwEJ

Answer (score 0):

Hope the elements are not dynamic, and you have a fixed structure of elements around the search box. After finalizing the element structure and the styling of them you have to identify the height of the `textbox` element. At the moment it is 47px. We will use this value in the following css.

Next add the following styles into the css.

```
.textbox {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -23px;
}
```

Please note that the value of the `margin-top` is half of the 47px( half of the `textbox` element. )

**Edit**

Add the following line into your jquery code.

```
$('.forminput').on('submit', function(event) {
    $('.textbox').addClass('pull-up');
```

After that, update you css with the following additional styles.

```
.textbox {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -23px;
}
.textbox.pull-up {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Didnt get wanted result. Search box stayed fixed at the middle of the screen. I want it to go to the top, above search results.
I want to implement this => https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/wGqEga/